# connecting android application to database on the server?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Iam trying  to make a connection between my database on the MYSQL(iam using the WAMP server) and android application , but when i run the application  an exception is raised  , i fixed the log cat and its points to this statement 
jArray = new JSONArray(result);

```
03-18 12:48:59.580: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
```

why this exception occur ?and how i can solve it ?

thanks in advanced..

this is my code :
**City.php:**

```
          <?php
           mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
           mysql_select_db("Deal");
           $sql=mysql_query("select * from City where Name like 'R%' ");
           while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
           $output[]=$row;
           print(json_encode($output));
           mysql_close();
              ?>
```

**the java class:**

```
public class ConnectionActivity extends ListActivity {

int ct_id;
String[] ct_name = null;
JSONArray jArray;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    // http post
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/city.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // paring data

            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                ct_name = new String[jArray.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ct_id = json_data.getInt("City_ID");
                    ct_name[i] = json_data.getString("Name");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            ListView lv;
            lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ct_name);
            setListAdapter(adapter);



}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
        Toast.makeText(this,"You have selected " + ct_name[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

**log:**

```
             03-18 13:28:46.923: W/ActivityThread(623): Application Com.Connection is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
             03-18 13:28:46.973: I/System.out(623): Sending WAIT chunk
             03-18 13:28:46.983: I/dalvikvm(623): Debugger is active
             03-18 13:28:47.174: I/System.out(623): Debugger has connected
             03-18 13:28:47.183: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:47.383: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:47.583: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:47.783: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:47.993: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:48.193: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:48.403: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:48.603: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:48.803: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:49.003: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:49.203: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:49.413: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
             03-18 13:28:49.613: I/System.out(623): debugger has settled (1497)
             03-18 13:30:17.593: E/log_tag(623): Error in http       connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
               03-18 13:30:34.315: E/log_tag(623): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: can you show us the received JSON string? Are you sure you didn't get an exception before and result is still null?

Comment: when i run the application an exception occur , and the emulator close it " force close "

Comment: OK, this doesn't help much. please print "result" before parsing it, so we would know what's its value. Also, a full log of the exception will help as well.

Comment: I made the section of parsing data as comment the i debug the application to know the value of the result , and i found that there is an error in the connection  , this is the log  after doing that

Comment: please edit your question and add the log there, it won't be readable as a comment.

Comment: why there is a connection error ? how i can solve it ?

Comment: Add the whole error log. This is still not sufficient.

Comment: Also it would be of help if you print the contents of `result`, just before this line: `jArray = new JSONArray(result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error as you try to perform HTTP connection on the main thread:

```
03-18 13:30:17.593: E/log_tag(623): Error in http       connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

As far as I can see, the HTTP code is correct, but you are running it on the UI thread. This is not allowed. You need to perform such long actions on a background thread. Android gives you a very easy to use facilities to perform long action on the background and publish the results on the main (UI) thread. One of the most useful is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). I would recommend that you read [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), as it will help you a lot IMO.

Comment: I dont have a lot of information about connecting android with MYSQL via a web service I read tutorials over the net and this is my first try of doing this and i do as it done in the tutorial

Comment: thanks for helping me , i will read them and an i hope that the connection work successfully